# preg_replace - replace a tag that appears 3 or more times

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use preg_replace to replace `<br />` when it appears 3 or more times, it should be replaced with `<br /><br />`

I'm trying to use this: `$text=preg_replace('/(<br \/>){3,}/', '<br /><br />', $text);`
Any body know whats wrong with my code?

So, just to confirm... `<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />` should be replaced with `<br /><br />`

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://codepad.org/9jG5ljjn

Comment: Show us input for which your script doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex works just fine, the problem is if you encounter:

- `<br>`
- `<br    -multiple spaces- >`
- `<br/>`
- `<br    -multiple spaces- />`
- `<br />  <br />` note the space(s) between the 2 br's
- `<br> -newlines- <br>`

So here's a solution:

```
$text = '<br    /><br><br   /><br   ><br  /><br><br/><br   /><br><br>
<br/>

<br/>
';
$text=preg_replace('/(<br\s*\/?>\s*){3,}/', '<br /><br />', $text);
var_dump($text); // output: string '<br /><br />' (length=12)
```

**[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/oY6fU8)**